# ASP.net firing jQuery AFTER asp UPDATE

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a formview which launches in editmode and allows the user to select yes or no from a dropdown and hit the 'save' button which is the Formviews Update command:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="CustomerEdit">
<ItemTemplate>
hello
</ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerNameLabel2" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="CustID" runat="server" visible="false"
            Text='<%# Bind("CustID") %>' />
            <br>
            <br></br>
        Is This Your Customer?
        <br>
        <br>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IsThisMyCustomer") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br>
        <br>
        <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CommandName="Update" Text="Save"  />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

This button also has JQuery behind it

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id$='Button']").click(function () {
        var div = $("div");
        $("img").hide();
        div.animate({ height: '300px', opacity: '0.4' }, "slow");
        div.animate({ width: '300px', opacity: '0.8' }, "slow", function () {
        window.location.href = "MyCustomers.aspx";
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now when the user hits the button, the Jquery script kicks in, then about halfway through the animation of the jquery script, the SQL update through the FormView Update command kicks in, essentially stopping jquery from doing its stuff and launching the itemtemplate of the formview as per a regular update.

What I want is the SQL update to occur and postback, then the jquery fire straight after.

What's the best approach to doing this

Comment: You seem to be confusing client-side and server-side functionality.  When a post-back occurs, the JavaScript is entirely unloaded and then loaded again from scratch when the page renders again.  If you want something to happen from JavaScript after a post-back, it needs to happen when that page re-renders.  Maybe include the JavaScript to perform this action from the server-side event handler.  And instead being a `click` event just have it happen directly in the `ready` event?  It doesn't seem to make for an ideal UX, re-loading a page *just* to redirect to another page.

Comment: I am very confused David. OK - so how would I set the jquery to run after a postback after hitting that button? I edited the jquery to this;      
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {             which makes it go through a constant animation loop :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing client-side and server-side functionality.  The order of events you're observing is this:

- Load the page
- Bind the click event to the element
- Click the element (begins the animation)
- Reload the page
- Bind the click event to the element

Your click event is really only accomplishing one thing, redirecting the user to another page.  If the page is being reloaded anyway, then why not do that from server-side code?

```
Response.Redirect("MyCustomers.aspx");
```

It doesn't have the animation, but since you're reloading the page anyway then the animation is kind of moot.  If you want to have the animation then you probably *don't* want to reload the page, in which case you'll want to start looking into AJAX for interacting with the server from JavaScript code.  (Which can be a pretty big subject, especially when dealing with WebForms controls.  It's often better in that case to just "do it the WebForms way" and not try to mess with them.)

---

In your comment above, you said you tried this...

```
$(window).load(function () { $(document).ready(function () { ...
```

That's... not right.  Don't just randomly mix and match jQuery code, understand what it is you're doing here.  You're binding events (such as `ready`) inside of an event handler (such as `load`), which can get pretty strange pretty fast.  Separate the event you want to respond to from the code you use to respond to it.  For example, consider what you have here:

```
$("input[id$='Button']").click(function () {
    //...
});
```

This doesn't *execute* the code inside the function, it binds that function *to be executed* when the `click` event happens.  The same is true of this structure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id$='Button']").click(function () {
        //...
    });
});
```

This binds a function to be executed when the `ready` event happens.  That function, in turn, binds another function to be executed when the `click` event happens.

Consider for example what I mentioned in my comment above... If you *really* want to animate the element and then redirect *after* the page reloads (which I still contend is a pretty poor UX, to be honest) then you would do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $("div");
    $("img").hide();
    div.animate({ height: '300px', opacity: '0.4' }, "slow");
    div.animate({ width: '300px', opacity: '0.8' }, "slow", function () {
    window.location.href = "MyCustomers.aspx";
    });
});
```

This skips the `click` event and just sets that code to execute immediately on the `ready` event.  Which means it'll execute when the page loads, basically.  Which also means that you don't want to always include this in the page (otherwise you'd never be able to view the page for more than a moment).  You'd want to only include it dynamically from the post-back which should cause this redirect.

---

Ultimately, you need to separate your client-side functionality from your server-side functionality.  If you're just redirecting after a form post (which is what you're doing), then redirect from server-side code.  If you want the bells and whistles of client-side animations and UX, don't use WebForms post-backs.